# Vaadin Spring Boot @autowired field returns null in a view

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, autowired, vaadin-flow

First off,  please excuse my question due to my being new to spring boot ecosystem. In my application, I've a vaadin page, where I want to submit user details to DB, using repository. In my view class, I've added them as @autowired fields, however, during the runtime, I see that their values are run so the operation fails. I know that to benefit from @autowired, the instances should not be created newly during constructing but I couldn't figure out how I should do it on my own. Here are my classes:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginAwareComposite extends Composite<Div> {

@Autowired
private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

public LoginAwareComposite() {
}

@Override
protected void onAttach(AttachEvent event) {
    super.onAttach(event);
    UserCredentials userPrincipal = UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute(UserCredentials.class);

    if (userPrincipal != null) {
        // --- NOT LOGGED IN
        UI.getCurrent().navigate(AddressBookManagementView.class);
    } 

}
```

}

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Route(value = "account")
@Theme(value = Lumo.class, variant = Lumo.LIGHT)
public class AddressBookManagementView extends LoginAwareComposite {

private VerticalLayout pageLayout = new VerticalLayout();

public AddressBookManagementView() {
    getContent().setSizeFull();
    getContent().add(initPage());

}

private Component initPage() {
    pageLayout.getStyle().set("padding-left", "0px");
    pageLayout.getStyle().set("padding-bottom", "0px");
    pageLayout.getStyle().set("padding-right", "0px");
    pageLayout.getStyle().set("overflow", "auto");
    pageLayout.setSizeFull();

    pageLayout.add(new HeaderLayout(), new BodyLayout(), new FooterLayout());

    return pageLayout;
}
```

}

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@SpringComponent
public class BodyLayout extends VerticalLayout {

// some fields

@Autowired
EmailRepository emailRepository;

@Autowired
FaxRepository faxRepository;

public BodyLayout() {
    init(); //this function inits the view, and eventually inits the on click event for submit button , which then calls my function
}

private void myFunction() {
//here i use the repository entities but they do return null although they are autowired
}
```

So what happens is,  in BodyLayout's constructor we call init() function which is used to init the layout and give functionality buttons etc, one of subfunctions inside the init method gives functionality to submit button using myFunction. MyFuction uses the repository entity but it returns null.

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious: you are sure that nowhere in BodyLayout do you do something like `emailRepository = new EmailRepository();`. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Route(value = "account")
@Theme(value = Lumo.class, variant = Lumo.LIGHT)
@UIScope
@SpringComponent
public class AddressBookManagementView extends LoginAwareComposite {

private VerticalLayout pageLayout = new VerticalLayout();

@Autowired
BodyLayout bodyLayout;

public AddressBookManagementView(BodyLayout bodyLayout) {
    this.bodyLayout = bodyLayout;
    getContent().setSizeFull();
    getContent().add(initPage());

}

private Component initPage() {
    pageLayout.getStyle().set("padding-left", "0px");
    pageLayout.getStyle().set("padding-bottom", "0px");
    pageLayout.getStyle().set("padding-right", "0px");
    pageLayout.getStyle().set("overflow", "auto");
    pageLayout.setSizeFull();

    pageLayout.add(new HeaderLayout(), bodyLayout, new FooterLayout());

    return pageLayout;
}
```

Then BodyLayout is

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@UIScope
@SpringComponent
public class BodyLayout extends VerticalLayout {

private final EmailRepository emailRepository;

private final FaxRepository faxRepository;

@Autowired
public BodyLayout(EmailRepository emailRepository, FaxRepository faxRepository) {
    this.emailRepository = emailRepository;
    this.faxRepository = faxRepository;
    init();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using springboot with vaadin ensure the following :

- Make sure that the `@Repository` annotation is used on your repository interfaces like on `EmailRepository`.
- Try using constructor injection for your repository classes like :

Try like below :

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
public class BodyLayout extends VerticalLayout {

// some fields

private final EmailRepository emailRepository;

private final FaxRepository faxRepository;

@Autowired
public BodyLayout(EmailRepository emailRepository, FaxRepository faxRepository) {
    this.emailRepository = emailRepository;
    this.faxRepository = faxRepository;
    init(); //this function inits the view, and eventually inits the on click event for submit button , which then calls my function
}

private void myFunction() {
//here i use the repository entities but they do return null although they are autowired
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but I still couldn't get rid of null problem, if i use the pattern you provide, I need constructor info for bodylayout, that means in addressbook managementview i need to again provide instances of these repository fields, i added also uiscope and spring component to addressbook view, and create autowired fields for repos there too to ibject bodylayouts constuctor it still gives me null :/

Comment: Two important things: 1. If you use field injection (@Autowired on a field), it will not be available in the constructor, only afterwards. 2. Whether you use field injection or constructor injection, it won't work if you create the instance yourself. You need to let Spring create it for you.

Comment: Hey Erik thank you so muhc, but in order to embed a view in the page i need a new instance of BodyLayout, how can i instantiate it without making (new) keyword then?

Comment: @AhmetEroğlu Erik is right about using new keyword won't allow you to use spring bean injection . Please share that code where you use BodyLayout class.

Comment: Hi @Ananthapadmanabhan it is already shared in the question, AddressBookManagementView is the view where its used

Comment: You autowire it ;) As simple as `public AddressBookManagementView(BodyLayout bodyLayout) { ...`. When you navigate to a view with Vaadin & Spring, constructor arguments will automatically be created. But you should add the `@UIScope` or `@Scope("prototype")` annotation to the `BodyLayout`, otherwise it will use the same component for all users, which will break your application.

Comment: Is this the constructor of AddressBookManagementView? If so, how can you write BodyLayout bodyLayout? because u need to pass a variable to constructor, and if i add BodyLayout field to addressbookmanagementview class as autowired, and call it in the consturcotr as bodyLayout, it says its null :/

Answer (score 2):

Roughly only `@Route`, layouts, and the vaadin init listener takes part in automatic dependency injection (that is: the vaadin spring integration asks the spring context to build them).  If you do `new MyClass()` it *never* takes part in DI.  Using field based injection with `@Autowired` hides this problem - so using constructor based injection is the "industry standard". The other way around is to not build your own instances, if you want to take part in DI but ask the spring context to build an instance for you.